# Deployment of Azure order issue Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

When deploying Azure resources with Terraform Cloud I'm expierencing an unexpected bahaviour.
It looks like the order of deployment or the wait time between the resources is failing.
The error says that the deployment of the network inteface failed because the subnet is not created.

I already tried to implement the depends_on function, but this doesnt seem to help at all.

```
# Create a virtual network within the core resource group
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "avd_default" {
  name                = "Vnet_${var.prefix}_Core-Prod"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.location
  address_space       = [var.avd_address_space]
}

# Create a Core internal subnet within vNet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "avd_default_core_internal" {
  name                 = "Subnet_${var.prefix}_Core-Prod"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.avd_default.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.core_address_prefixes]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.avd_default
  ]

}

# Create a Core external subnet within vNet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "avd_default_core_external" {
  name                 = "Subnet_${var.prefix}_Internet-Prod"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.avd_default.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.internet_address_prefixes]

    depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.avd_default
  ]

}

# Create the Network interface for DC01
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "avd_default_dc01" {
  name                = "dc01-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.name
  dns_servers                   = [var.private_ip_dc01,"8.8.8.8"]

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.avd_default_core_internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = var.private_ip_dc01
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_subnet.avd_default_core_internal
  ]

}

# Create DC01 Windows Server 2022
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "avd_default_dc01" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-dc01"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.avd_default_core_rg.location
  size                = var.dc01_vm_size
  admin_username      = "username"
  admin_password      = var.dc01_admin_password
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.avd_default_dc01.id]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = "128"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

Error written below:

```
Error: Subnet "Subnet_gro_Core-Prod" (Virtual Network "Vnet_gro_Core-Prod" / Resource Group "RG_gro_Core-Prod") was not found!
with azurerm_subnet_route_table_association.avd_default_wg
on main.tf line 316, in resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "avd_default_wg":
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "avd_default_wg" {


Error: creating Network Interface: (Name "dc01-nic" / Resource Group "RG_gro_Core-Prod"): network.InterfacesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidResourceReference" Message="Resource /subscriptions/xxxb91c5-4fe5-44af-9c98-cdd8e73ee240/resourceGroups/RG_gro_Core-Prod/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Vnet_gro_Core-Prod/subnets/Subnet_gro_Core-Prod referenced by resource /subscriptions/xxxb91c5-4fe5-44af-9c98-cdd8e73ee240/resourceGroups/RG_gro_Core-Prod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/dc01-nic was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region." Details=[]
with azurerm_network_interface.avd_default_dc01
on main.tf line 78, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "avd_default_dc01":
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "avd_default_dc01" {



Error: creating Network Interface: (Name "wg-nic-internal" / Resource Group "RG_gro_Watchguard-Prod"): network.InterfacesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidResourceReference" Message="Resource /subscriptions/xxxb91c5-4fe5-44af-9c98-cdd8e73ee240/resourceGroups/RG_gro_Core-Prod/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Vnet_gro_Core-Prod/subnets/Subnet_gro_Core-Prod referenced by resource /subscriptions/xxxb91c5-4fe5-44af-9c98-cdd8e73ee240/resourceGroups/RG_gro_Watchguard-Prod/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/wg-nic-internal was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region." Details=[]
with azurerm_network_interface.avd_default_wg_internal
on main.tf line 156, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "avd_default_wg_internal":
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "avd_default_wg_internal" {
```

Running the terraform deploy command for a second time after this errors it is working as expected.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Hi, i've added the errors to the opening post.

Comment: There is no need of explicit `depends_on` if you have referenced that argument in dependent resources. I see you haven't posted the complete code as I don't see `avd_default_wg_internal` nic resource.

Comment: You can analyze the graph walk of terraform objects with `terraform graph -plan <plan-file> -h` to see how resources are created & referenced.

Comment: Is it possible to run this through Terraform cloud?